# Dynamically changing Cell Renderer of ag-grid using param

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm new at ag grid and I'm trying to return some value according a boolean.

So I tried:

```
{ headerName: 'Teste', field: 'active'
cellRendererParams: (params: any) => { return params.value === true ? 'sim' : 'nao'}
}
```

but the cell still show me the value true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need just to display a different value, use [value formatter](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/value-formatters/):

```js
valueFormatter: params => params.value === true ? 'sim' : 'nao'
```